# Cannot parse the parameter while instantiation in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to open a specific profile using Firefox, but i don't understand why i cannot parse the parameter on the last line. 
The imports are:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

[image]

Comment: paste your imports.

Comment: @muraliselenium i edited the question

Comment: delete all imports and try importing again. i hope this issue goes out but it is depreciated to use FirefoxDriver(profile); we need to pass options. check my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On latest versions, we need to use options, for firefox FirefoxOptions

```
  FirefoxOptions options=new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProfile(profile);
    WebDriver dd=new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `FirefoxDriver` does not have a constructor that takes a `FirefoxProfile` as a parameter.

Looking at the documentation, you can pass a `FirefoxOptions` instance and set the profile there:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(myprofile); //set your options here
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to open it!!!

This is how i did it:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\wn6am1jt.MyProfile");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(file);
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setProfile(profile); //set your options here
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```